# Aligning output column using setw in C++

Tags: c++, text-alignment, setw

I have been reading about setw for column widths, however setting a width for each colum does not seem to be aligning the last two columns. I have tried using the right align, however it also changes alignment for the left two columns as well, which I don't want. In the end I'd like everything to be left aligned. Is there an easier way of doing this other than setw?

Current code:

```
void print_head()
{
  cout.setf(ios::left);
  cout << setw(16) << "Operation" 
       << setw(32) << "z" 
       << setw(8) << "Cost" 
       << setw(8) << "Total" << endl;

  for (int i=0; i<64; ++i) cout << "-";
  cout << endl;
}

print_head();
cout.setf(ios::left);
cout << setw(16) << "Initial String" 
    << setw(32) << test1 
    << setw(8) << "0" 
    << setw(8) << "0" << endl;
for (int g = minops[0] + minops[1] - 1;g>-1;g--){
    string a;
    for(stringstream ss(operations[g]); getline(ss, a, ','); )  // that's all ! 
        v.push_back(a);

    //cout << v[current] << "\n";
    if (v[current] == "c"){
        z = sright(z, cursorg);
        current++;
        cout << setw(16) << "right" 
            << setw(32) << z
            << setw(8) << "0" 
            << setw(8) << tcost << endl;
    }else if (v[current] == "d"){
        z = sdelete(z, cursorg);
        size = size - 1;
        tcost = tcost + 2;
        cout << setw(16) << "delete" 
            << setw(32) << z
            << setw(8) << "2" 
            << setw(8) << tcost << endl;
        //cout << "cursor out of delete: " << cursorg << "\n";
        current = current + 2;
    }else if (v[current] == "r"){
        z = sreplace(z, cursorg, test2, stoi(v[current+1]), stoi(v[current+2]));
        int printtemp = stoi(v[current+2]);
        string s(1,test2[printtemp]);
        string tempstr = "replace by " + s;
        tcost = tcost + 4;
        cout << setw(16) << tempstr
            << setw(32) << z
            << setw(8) << "4" 
            << setw(8) << tcost << endl;
        current = current + 3;
    }else if (v[current] == "i"){   
        z = sinsert(z, test2, cursorg, stoi(v[current+1]));
        size = size - 1;
        tcost = tcost + 3;
        int printtemp = stoi(v[current+1]);
        string s(1,test2[printtemp]);
        string tempstr = "insert " + s;
        cout << setw(16) << tempstr
            << setw(32) << z
            << setw(8) << "3" 
            << setw(8) << tcost << endl;
        current = current + 2;
    }else{

    }

    //cout << operations[g] << "\n";
    //cout << "z is: " << z << "\n";

}
cout << "\n";
cout << "minimum operations is: " << minops[0] << "\n";
```

This is my current output, however I want the cost and total cost to be a neat aligned column under the header. How do I use setw to fix my alignment?

[image: This is my current output]

Delete implementation:

```
string sdelete(string input, int &cursor){ //deletes the letter under the cursor, cost 2
    if (cursor == (input.length() + 1)){
        //do nothing
    }else{
        input[cursor] = NULL;
        cursor = cursor+1;
    }
    //DEBUG cout << "delete input: " << input << "\n";
    //DEBUG cout << "cursor in delete: " << cursor << "\n";

    return input;
}
```

Comment: Looks like your `delete` logic is deleting a character out of the string, after the width has been allotted. It's eating into your string space.

Comment: @Kai I have gone ahead and added in my delete function in my original post. I need to delete certain characters from the string to modify. Would there be a way to add the width back every time delete runs? In order to keep a consistent string space.

Comment: Setting particular characters in a `std::string` to 0 (`NULL`) is unidiomatic. Your output stream is still consuming these `NULL` characters (apparently! I had no idea it would work that way), and counting them against the field width, but not actually printing anything to the console. Use `std::string::erase` instead. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase

Comment: And then on the flipside, use `std::string::insert` to insert characters. The characters are simply removed from the container with erase. No need to keep track of where the "start" of the string is anymore. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ setw not aligning columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667524/c-setw-not-aligning-columns)